# using \KeyValue in xtemplate for instance key-types

Tags: latex3, xtemplate

I came across a problem in `xtemplate` with using `\KeyValue` for keys of type `instance`. Instance key-types haven't been documented yet, so I could just be doing it wrong.
Here's the smallest example I could come up with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xtemplate}
\ExplSyntaxOn

\DeclareObjectType { format } {1}
\DeclareObjectType { tagged } {2}

\DeclareTemplateInterface { format } { format-text } {1}
  {
    font : tokenlist = \normalfont ,
  }
\DeclareTemplateInterface { tagged } { tagged-text } {2}
  {
    main : instance { format } = normal ,
    tag  : instance { format } = \KeyValue { main } ,
  }

\tl_new:N \l__mwe_tl
\DeclareTemplateCode { format } { format-text } {1}
  { font = \l__mwe_tl , }
  {
    \AssignTemplateKeys
    { \l__mwe_tl #1 }
  }
\DeclareTemplateCode { tagged } { tagged-text } {2}
  {
    main = \__mwe_main:n ,
    tag  = \__mwe_tag:n ,
  }
  {
    \AssignTemplateKeys
    \__mwe_tag:n {#1} \__mwe_main:n {#2}
  }

\DeclareInstance  { format } { normal } { format-text }
  {}
\DeclareInstance  { tagged } { specific } { tagged-text }
  {
    main = normal ,
    tag  = normal ,
  }
\DeclareInstance  { tagged } { default } { tagged-text }
  {
    main = normal ,
  }
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}

\UseInstance {tagged} {specific} {Y:~} {This one works.}

\UseInstance {tagged} {default} {N:~} {This one fails.}

\end{document}
```

(the bug report at https://github.com/latex3/latex3/issues/131 suggested trying it a second time, but that didn't work either).

The relevant bits of the log file:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.20 (MiKTeX 2.9.7200 64-bit) 
Package: expl3 2019-10-02 L3 programming layer (loader) 
Package: xtemplate 2019-05-28 L3 Experimental prototype document functions

! Package xtemplate Error: The instance '\KeyValue {main}' of type 'format' is
(xtemplate)                unknown.
For immediate help type H <return>.
 ...                                              
l.61 ...{tagged} {default} {N:~} {This one fails.}
```

Does anyone know how to make `\KeyValue` evaluate earlier?